# Correct MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

*I am in the Process of building a web system for My Company. I couldnt get the correct sql query for search query to meet my conditions. Below i post the details about the search function*

[image]

A user can input any of the fields and the query must return all the results meeting the conditions given ignoring the fields that aren't filled..

Suppose user selects Sector Iraq and Choose Rating 5, then the query must return all customers in sector iraq with rating 5.

Note : A user can have multiple sectors. Below is an example code for sectors while adding a new Customer. ie if a sector is selected "1" is entered into DB else "" is entered to corresponding field(sector_india)

```
if (empty($_POST['sector_india'])){
        $sector_india = '';}
    else{
        $sector_india = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sector_india', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
```

and the code for Checkbox while searching is given below :

```
if (empty($_POST['sector_india'])){
        $sector_india = '0';}
    else{
        $sector_india = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sector_india', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Below I paste my SQL Query.. I couldnt get the exact query to meet the above conditions. Can someone help me

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE ( name LIKE '%$custname%' AND contactperson LIKE '%$custperson%' AND area LIKE '%$area%' AND rating LIKE '%$rating%')
     AND (sector_india = '$sector_india' OR sector_iran = '$sector_iran' OR sector_fareast = '$sector_fareast' OR sector_gcc = '$sector_gcc' OR sector_iraq = '$sector_iraq') ORDER BY rating DESC;");
        }
```

Comment: I hope your query isn't build by string concatenation (but it looks like it is). Use prepared statements or suffer sql injection attack. (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Can you describe what your query behaves like? Does it return anything at all, which part does it fail at?

Comment: its does currently return values... but suppose i do not want to choose any sectors (for eg : i want to list all the customers with rating 5 irrespective of the sectors), then the query doesn't return any value at all because i haven't selected any sectors. If you see the query once again, you will notice the query returns as it is constructed... 

But i couldn't write the query for what i need... I'm a beginner btw

Comment: @HoneyBadger : yeah sure i will do it once i get the query working correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can do as following.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE ";
 $operator = '';
 if (!empty($_POST['custname']){
      //Define operator for next concatenate.
      $operator = ' AND ';
      $custname = $_POST['custname'];
      $query .= " name LIKE '%$custname% ";
  }


 if (!empty($_POST['custperson']){

      $custperson= $_POST['custperson'];
      $query .= $operator. " contactperson LIKE '%$custperson%'";
      $operator = ' AND ';
  }
  // Similar code for all thing which connect with AND operator.

  $query2 = '';
  $operator2 = '';
  if(!empty($_POST['sector_india'])
  {
     $sector_india = $_POST['sector_india'];
     $query2 .= "sector_india = '$sector_india'";
     $operator2 = ' OR ';
  }
  if(!empty($_POST['sector_iran'])
  {
     $sector_iran= $_POST['sector_iran'];
     $query2 .= $operator2."sector_iran= '$sector_iran'";
     $operator2 = ' OR ';
  }
  // similar query for all other country

  now 
  $query = $query. $operator .'('. $query2 .') ORDER BY rating DESC';  
  $result = $conn->query($query);
```

Please note that i have not Filtered data for security. Please consider to filter them for security.

Comment: is there any other ingenious way?

Comment: @user3765203 Yes, As you can see my code sample has code repeated stuff for different post parameter. You can create create method simply for below line and make function for following lines `if (!empty($_POST['custperson']){

      $custperson= $_POST['custperson'];
      $query .= $operator. " contactperson LIKE '%$custperson%'";
      $operator = ' AND ';
  }` If you not clear. Please comment again. i will update my answer for that. You can also use some helper class like [this](https://github.com/ezSQL/ezSQL)